# Activity freeses after passing to it from SurfaceView activity

Tags: android

Have an activity with SurfaceView and a thread to paint on it (from [this](https://o7planning.org/en/10521/android-2d-game-tutorial-for-beginners) example). Here is GameSurface's finalization code:

```
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    boolean retry = true;
    while(retry) {
        try {
            this.gameThread.setRunning(false);
            this.gameThread.join();
        }catch(InterruptedException e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        retry = true;
    }
}
```

(don't really understand the logic of having retry always true, layed a bit with it but got no positive effect)

Here is the game thread:

```
package org.mineprogramming.laserminigolf;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class GameThread extends Thread {

    private boolean running;
    private GameSurface gameSurface;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

    public GameThread(GameSurface gameSurface, SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder)  {
        this.gameSurface = gameSurface;
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()  {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        while(running)  {
            Canvas canvas= null;
            try {
                // Get Canvas from Holder and lock it.
                canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

                // Synchronized
                synchronized (canvas)  {
                    this.gameSurface.update();
                    this.gameSurface.draw(canvas);

                }
            }catch(Exception e)  {
                // Do nothing.
            } finally {
                if(canvas!= null)  {
                    // Unlock Canvas.
                    this.surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
            long now = System.nanoTime() ;
            // Interval to redraw game
            // (Change nanoseconds to milliseconds)
            long waitTime = (now - startTime)/1000000;
            if(waitTime < 10)  {
                waitTime= 10; // Millisecond.
            }
            System.out.print(" Wait Time="+ waitTime);

            try {
                // Sleep.
                this.sleep(waitTime);
            } catch(InterruptedException ignored)  { }
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.print(".");
        }
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean running)  {
        this.running= running;
    }
}
```

Now I start some other activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

And this activity is not responding (it is shown, however). 
Tried also to start it for result.
The same thing when returning back via finish() from my activity with SurfaceView to another one.

After debugging for a little while, I see that initialization of the activity is successful, it freezes somewhere later

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that was it. Retry was always true. This variant of finalization helped me:

```
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    boolean retry = true;
    while(retry) {
        try {
            this.gameThread.setRunning(false);
            this.gameThread.join();
            retry = false;
        }catch(InterruptedException e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure it is the best one, but it works for me.